# Spark multiple jobs error

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to submit multiple applications on spark.

After first application is completed, Spark allocates all the worker nodes to driver. As a result no cores are left for execution

My Environment: 2 worker nodes each with 1 core and 2GB RAM, the driver is running on the nodes.

Spark submit command: `./spark-submit --class Main --master spark://ip:6066 --deploy-mode cluster /jarPath`

So if I submit 3 jobs, after first is completed, second and third gets one core each for their drivers and no cores are left for execution.

Please tell a way to resolve this.

Comment: In which mode are you running? spark local/standalone/yarn-client/yarn-cluster ? **please provide spark-submit command**

Comment: Does your driver is running on one of those 2 worker nodes?

Comment: ./spark-submit --class Main --master spark://ip:6066 --deploy-mode cluster /jarPath

Comment: yes driver is running on one of those workers

Comment: which **spark version** are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try killing old instances of spark:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#launching-spark-applications

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <master url> <driver ID>
```

You can find the driver ID through the standalone Master web UI at http://:8080.

Comment: I want to execute these in these fashion only as output of one is input to other .So driver cannot be killed for any application.

Comment: How do you provide data from the driver to another spark job? are you using "collect()"? It doesn't seems like a good practice of spark development.

Comment: I am saving data to HDFS.

Comment: If you save the data to HDFS - why can't you kill the driver?

Comment: I have created an automation for these tasks. So I am not submitting the code, code for automation is submitting these applications to spark.

Comment: @TejasviSharma - it feels like you took the wrong path, two small nodes trying to run several spark jobs... I'd change the architecture of both - your hardware, and your spark application